# How to solve problems when installing semPlot

Tags: semplot

please help whith this error when installing semPlot. Thank you so much!!

This is the error message:

> install.packages("semPlot")
> --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
> Warning: failed to download mirrors file (no fue posible abrir la URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file 'C:/Users/mariagf/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.3.1/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/src/contrib:
> no fue posible abrir la URL 'https://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
> no fue posible abrir la URL 'https://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
> Warning messages:
> 1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
> URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'SSL connect error'
> 2: package ‘semPlot’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages